# Restrict form POST to Unity only

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to verify that a form post comes from Unity? For example, I have a form (using Codeigniter, by the way) that logs the user in. I want to make sure that the POST data comes from the WebGL Unity build and is not directly accessible by going to the form page.

Is this a thing that's a thing?

Comment: thers probably something unique in the headers of the request you could use

Comment: This isn't really an SO question.  Yes it's doable. You should look into cryptographic signatures/digital signing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this really depends on how you want to that.

> Is there a way to verify that a form post comes from Unity?

**Yes**

You can use a header to set a "User-Agent" to "WEBGL-BUILD" or any unique value:

```
var uwr = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
uwr.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
uwr.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "WEBGL-BUILD");
yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
```

or use form to send a value that shows the request is from WebGL Build:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("User-Agent", "WEBGL-BUILD");
UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
```

Then check the header or form on the server to see if they match.

> Restrict form POST to Unity only

**No**.

You can't do this. The reason is that people can change that. Even with the two methods I mentioned above, anyone can still make reverse engineer your program and find out what you are sending to the server then create a fake request with any programming language and send it to the server.

Implementing what I said above will only make it harder to abuse your server but it **cannot** totally restrict form POST to Unity only. Just stick to token-based authentication. Even better, use oauth2.